# Internet Printing Protocol (IPP) for nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, printing, ipp-protocol

I am trying print the pdf file in my local using printer. This is a code, tried to print.

```
fs.readFile('documents/AccountStatement.pdf', function(err, data) { 
    if (err)
        throw err;
    var printer = ipp.Printer("http://hostname:631/ipp/printer");
    var msg = {
    "operation-attributes-tag": {
      "requesting-user-name": "KUMA1936",
      "job-name": "My Test Job",
      "document-format": "application/pdf"
    },
    data: data
    };
    printer.execute("Print-Job", msg, function(err, res){
        console.log(res);
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

In the above code what does printer.execute() method and "Print-Job" parameter. And what does 631 here.When i print the res,its shows

{ version: '1.1',
  statusCode: 'server-error-operation-not-supported',
  id: 442076,
  'operation-attributes-tag':
   { 'attributes-charset': 'utf-8',
     'attributes-natural-language': 'en-us' } }
err is null.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the API [docs](https://github.com/williamwicks/ipp#printerexecuteoperation-message-callback). The first parameter (string) is an operation defined by IPP.
Description about `Print-Job` operation is given [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911#section-3.2.1)

> ```
> 3.2.1 Print-Job Operation
>
>    This REQUIRED operation allows a client to submit a print job with
>    only one document and supply the document data (rather than just a
>    reference to the data).  See Section 15 for the suggested steps for
>    processing create operations and their Operation and Job Template
>    attributes.
> ```

You can see other IPP supported operations [here](https://github.com/williamwicks/ipp/blob/master/lib/enums.js#L52). 631 is the accepted port used for IPP, which uses TCP.

You can check more about the error [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911#section-13.1.5.2), which shows :

> ```
> 13.1.5.2 server-error-operation-not-supported (0x0501)
>
>    The IPP object does not support the functionality required to fulfill
>    the request. This is the appropriate response when the IPP object
>    does not recognize an operation or is not capable of supporting it.
>    See sections 3.1.6.1 and 3.1.7.
> ```

This means that there is no error in your code. Most likely your printer is not configured or does not support IPP. Last but not the least, the `IPP.Printer` has to be given the printer IP. So check the IP you are giving is valid (your code shows you gave hostname). From the project [page](https://github.com/williamwicks/ipp#internet-printing-protocol-ipp-for-nodejs) it is given :

> ```
> To find out if your printer supports IPP:
>
>  - Google your printer's specs
>  - Try: telnet YOUR_PRINTER 631. If it connects, that's a good sign.
>  - Use the '/examples/findPrinters.js' script.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just **share** the printer : *(like share with another)*

**So URL gonna be** *(you will be found by findPrinters.js)*

`http://My-Computer-Name.local.:631/printers/my_printer_name`

*This should be help if your printer donesnt connect (like USB) with your computer. But connect via lan.*

Answer (score 0):

- Look's like you get an IPP-Version-1.1-Response while sending IPP-2.0.
- Try downgrading to 1.1 by using the version-option